# What is the recommended way to release the UI from a long running background task in Blazor client-side

Tags: azure, blazor

Our Blazor (client-side) app is made up of many components all existing on the UI at the same time. One of these has to do a number of large data calls to Azure SQL. This component does these calls regardless of whether it has UI focus or not. Each of calls these can take up to 3 seconds to return its result during which it renders the UI unresponsive. How can we keep the UI responsive during these calls without using Blazor server-side. Using Task.Run etc does not help in single threaded architecture. Using loading spinners is also not an option as this still leaves the UI unresponsive and may not be visible to the user. Is there any way to achieve this goal in current Blazor 0.9.0?

Running latest Blazor preview release (0.9.0-preview3-19154-02)

Comment: Are you making calls to Azure directly from the client? I hope not as this would mean passing sensitive Azure connection strings etc. to the _client_ which is a massive security risk! I would expect this type of operation to be initiated on a client, sent to the server and then the server tracks the Azure task and updates the client. SignalR would be one way to do this, or perhaps running them as [Hosted Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2) ?

Comment: HostedServices as designed attempt to start another thread which is not possible in Blazor afaik. SignalR method may have better potential in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Invoke`, I modified `counter` example page to illustrate it, you will need a kind of singleton DI object to avoid running the process for twice.

Remember `Blazor` is an experimental project. Also, this answer is also an experimental approach.

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@functions {
    int currentCount = 0;

    void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    protected  override void OnInit()
    {
        Invoke(
            //here your task.
            async () =>
            {
                for(var i =0; i< 50; i++)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    currentCount++;
                    StateHasChanged();                    
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Still running ...");
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that and yes well aware its experimental been on it since 0.5 - will try out your suggestion

Comment: This method releases the UI from long running DB calls effectively. CPU intensive processing still seems to hold up the UI within the Invoke. Thanks for your help @dani herrera

Answer (score 1):

If async calls does not help then you can use browser workers, just need to implement some js interop.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at your sample web worker repositories a couple of days ago but they do not do exactly what I want. Good work though.

Comment: Yes, it had different purpose but you can easy adjust for you needs.

Comment: I am going to go through your browser worker sample again in detail in the morning and try apply it. HostingService doesnt do the job as it attempts to create another thread. Another option is to use async ajax call to do the data retrieval and wait on the response but this feels like it is breaking the model

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with Task().Start()

put your work in an async Task like so:

```
async Task MyWork()
{
    //sleep 10000
}
```

now from wherever you don't want this work to block call:

```
new Task( () => MyWork()).Start() );
```

I've only used this with Blazor Server, so haven't tested it with Client side Blazor which I hear can have different results because of its running on a single thread.

Comment: On WebAssembly this won't work, at best it does nothing. On Blazor server, use async/await and in very rare cases  Task.Run().

Comment: For my use case, I'm following an interface that doesn't allow async/await, so running the task like this works around that.

Comment: Still, Task.Run() probably has better defaults.

Answer (score -1):

the suggested answer did not work, for me, I ended up using :

```
 protected override void OnInitialized()
 {
    InvokeAsync(async () =>
    {
        myvar = await YourCodeHere();
        StateHasChanged();

    });
    base.OnInitialized();
}

public async Task<MyVarType> YourCodeHere()
{
    ...
}
```

Explanation: I have a class called MyVarType that I am using to display values on the Razor component. I have a myVar variable instantiated with that class, and initially it is empty. The component will render its default values immediately. Upon initializing the variable is then also being asynchronously assigned from the OnInitialized method. The YourCodeHere function could take several seconds. The Razor component rerenders when calling StateHasChanged() so it displays the loaded values.